# Spring and ServletContextListener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I read some articles and posts here about

```
@Autowired
ServletContext context;
```

Of my realization of `ServletContextListener` to `@Controller`. But I got a long exception when run it:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
Error creating bean with name 'trendsoftCtrl':
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'context':
No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency [javax.servlet.ServletContext]:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)};
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.ServletContext] found for dependency [javax.servlet.ServletContext]:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Here are my classes.

```
@WebListener
public class TRSCListner implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    String beanFileName = context.getInitParameter("springBeans");

    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load(beanFileName);
    ctx.refresh();
    NewsDao newsDao = ctx.getBean("newsDao", NewsDao.class);

    context.setAttribute("appContext", ctx);
    context.setAttribute("dao", newsDao);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = (GenericXmlApplicationContext) context.getAttribute("appContext");
    ctx.close();
}

}
```

And another

```
@Controller
public class TrendsoftCtrl {

@Autowired
ServletContext context; 

@RequestMapping ("/welcome")
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
    NewsDao newsDao = (NewsDao) context.getAttribute("dao");
    List<News> news = newsDao.getAll();

    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

    for (News n : news) {
        message.append(n.getCategory().getName() + "<br>");
        message.append(n.getName() + "<br>");
        message.append(n.getData() + "<br><br>");
    }

    return new ModelAndView("welcome", "news", message.toString());
}

public ServletContext getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(ServletContext context) {
    this.context = context;
}

}
```

Comment: Why do you inject `ServletContext` into your controller? It breaks the loose-coupling idea the Spring was designer for. You should declare your DAO class as standalone bean and configure your root context and servlet context properly. Try to use Spring Java configuration, see this link as an example: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/  You don't need to put any beans to the `ServletContext`manually

Comment: Ok. But I don't see anything about listeners there

Comment: Why do you use custom listener? Looks like you just put some beans to the context in your listener. You can avoid interacting with context at all, just use the Spring. You can configure these beans in declarative manner and inject 'em into your business classes with `@Autowired` annotation (or `@Inject` or ``@Resource). If you have a xml configuration you need to import, you can either rewrite it as Java config, or just import to the Java config, see this link: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-mixing-xml-and-javaconfig/

Comment: Just one question... Why? Spring already has the `ContextLoaderListener` which will load your configuration. Next to that passing the beans through the context is a bad idea as that basically beats the whole purpose of dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the @Autowired will perform the dependency checking to make sure the property has been wired properly. When Spring can’t find a matching bean to wire, it will throw an exception. To fix it, you can disable this checking feature by setting the “required” attribute of @Autowired to false.

@Autowired(required=false)

Even if Spring can’t find a matching bean, it will leave the person property unset.